# Which band of colour does r.reclass use?

Tags: qgis, qgis-grass-plugin

I have been trying to use the r.reclass tool edit my raster layer. So far it works as I use command such as  `0 thru 100 = 1` and it works.

However, as my raster layer has multiple colour bands (RGB), I am not sure which band does the r.reclass tool sample from.

Or does it use a combined value from all three bands? Is there a way for me to edit the individual band?